# How to access hive tables in pentaho

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, pentaho

I was used pentaho data integration 4.4.0 and using mongo hadoop connector [using this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop)  I was created successfully hadoop and mongo connections. Then I installed hive 0.11.0 and using above link I was created hive and mongo connections successfully. In my mongo contains one database name as pentaho and I created database in hive name as demo and using following command I was created new table name as pentho

```
CREATE TABLE pentaho
( 
  id INT,
  region STRING,
  year INT,
  q1 INT,
  q2 INT,
  q3 INT,
  q4 INT
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"id":"_id"}')
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://localhost:27017/pentaho.sales');
```

then I was write `select * from pentaho;` command on hive shell it shows all records presents in sales collections. 
  Then I was created model in pentaho using hadoop hive datasource set host as localhost database name as demo and port as 10000 and click on test then it shows popup connections made success. But when I was click on ok then new coming popup windows options like Schemas, Tables, Views, Synonyms but in table not contains any table which I was created in hive. So how can access hive tables in pentaho data source?

Answer (score 0):

After time I found where I was missing I set in my local hadoop conf/mapred-site.xml file I set port as localhost:9001 and when I start bi-server same port used for hsql. Then after changing mapred-site.xml port other than 9001 it work fine. :)